# Enumerating capture ALSA devices and capture from them

Tags: c, linux, audio, capture, alsa

I am writing a C program where I would like to enumerate all the capture devices in my system (in practice, I know I have three webcams plus the "integrated" microphone), recognize them and start capturing from them all at the same time.

I has some success using snd_device_name_hint() to enumerate all PCM devices and then snd_device_name_get_hint() to determine the "IOID" to see if they support capture. But now, how do I open the related device with snd_pcm_open() so that I can capture? I would like to use the "hw" interface as I do not want to overload the system with many conversion rates, so I would also like to see if there is a method to report the HW supported sampling frequencies.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`snd_device_name_hint()` can return multiple device names for the same hardware device (e.g., `plughw` and `hw`).
It can also returns devices that do not correspond to a single hardware device (such as `null`, or PulseAudio/Jack/Bluetooth devices).

To enumerate hardware devices, call `snd_card_next()` and `snd_ctl_pcm_next_device()` (see the aplay source code for an example).

To check whether a sample rate is supported, call `snd_pcm_hw_params_test_rate()`.

Comment: Yeah in fact I've found also this page: http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/aplay.htm where the author goes in detail on how to scan all cards, devices and subdevices and also how to set properties.