# Getting ALSA card information

Tags: c, linux, alsa

Once I have the card number (for example hw:0) how can I get information and descriptions from the ALSA library? I would like ot access the data similar to what I can find in /proc/asound/cards, for example:

```
 0 [CinemaTM       ]: USB-Audio - Microsoft® LifeCam Cinema(TM)
                      Microsoft Microsoft® LifeCam Cinema(TM) at usb-spear-ehci.0-1.1, high speed
```

As I have multiple such "cards" in my system, info like "CinemaTM", "USB-Audio" and "usb-ehci.0-1.1" help me to recognize what I need to open for capture.

In a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696926/enunerating-capture-alsa-devices-and-capture-from-them) I found out how to iterate over all the cards and capture devices in the system, now I'd like to retrieve information about those - but my first impression with the ALSA API is that it's quite big and cumbersome for a beginner to understand how do to things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the card's control device (which is also named `hw:0`, but doesn't have subdevices), and call `snd_ctl_card_info()`.

`snd_ctl_card_info_get_id()`: CinemaTM
`snd_ctl_card_info_get_driver()`: USB-Audio
`snd_ctl_card_info_get_name()`: Microsoft® LifeCam Cinema(TM)
`snd_ctl_card_info_get_longname()`: Microsoft Microsoft® ... at usb-...

Comment: Yes, "longname" is the one I wanted! Thanks!