# Use ALSA API to get all input audio devices

Tags: c, alsa

I want to write a code that uses ALSA API to iterate over all the audio devices and prints the devices which are defined as input (microphones).

This is my code:

```
#define MAX_DEV_STR_LEN 6
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    snd_ctl_t *ctlp;
    snd_ctl_card_info_t *info;
    int *rcard;
    int index, err;
    rcard = &index;
    index = -1;
    char *name = malloc(MAX_DEV_STR_LEN);
    while(1)
    {
        snd_card_next(rcard);
        if(index == -1)
            break;
        sprintf(name, "hw:%d", *rcard);
        if((err = snd_ctl_open(&ctlp, name, SND_CTL_NONBLOCK)) != 0)
        {
            printf("Error opening the card: %d\n", err);
            return err;
        }
        printf("Card number %d has opened succesfully\n", *rcard);
        snd_ctl_card_info_malloc(&info);
        if((err = snd_ctl_card_info(ctlp, info)) != 0)
        {
            printf("Error obtaining the info\n");
            return err;
        }


        // get info here...


        snd_ctl_card_info_clear(info);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to get the info I need.I searched [here](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/). But couldn't find a solution.

If anyone can guide me I will appreciate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the similar questions already? Here's [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19696926/11287083), it mentions that `snd_device_name_hint()` may help a lot with getting the list of `plughw` or `hw` devices. My suggestion is to take a look at the source code of the `aplay / arecord` command, especially the `pcm_list()` function - this seems to be the function preparing the list you want.

To check if your list is correct use `arecord -L`.

Comment: Turned out I didn't ask the right question but thank you for the reply!